# String.split() returns empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, split, srt

I was look for parsing SRT file and found some function using .split() but I get an empty array...

I think the problem comes from my SRT syntaxe but I don't understand what     **/(?:^|\n\n)\d+\n|\n+$/g** means inside .split() function.

These are the functions I found :

```
function srtTimeToSeconds(time) {
  var match = time.match(/(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d),(\d\d\d)/);
  var hours        = +match[1],
      minutes      = +match[2],
      seconds      = +match[3],
      milliseconds = +match[4];

  return (hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60) + (seconds) + (milliseconds / 1000);
}

function parseSrtLine(line) {
  var match = line.match(/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d) --> (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)\n(.*)/m);

  return {
    start: srtTimeToSeconds(match[1]),
    end:   srtTimeToSeconds(match[2]),
    text:  match[3].trim()
  };
}

function parseSrt(srt) {
  var lines = srt.split(/(?:^|\n\n)\d+\n|\n+$/g).slice(1, -2);

  return $.map(lines, parseSrtLine);
}
```

This is my SRT string :

```
const mySRT =
"0\
00:00:01,414 --> 00:00:03,613\
All the single ladies\
1\
00:00:03,805 --> 00:00:05,904\
All the single ladies\
2\
00:00:06,118 --> 00:00:08,717\
All the single ladies\"
```

this is my Javascript code :

```
const subtitles = parseSrt(mySRT);
console.log(subtitles);
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: The string */(?:^|\n\n)\d+\n|\n+$/g* inside the split method is a [regex expression](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp). you should read more about it to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @AmanB Thanks ! that's what I was looking for :)